# Loading CSV with fread stops because of to large string

Tags: r, performance, csv, ram

This is the command I'm using :

```
dallData <- fread("data.csv", showProgress = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("NULL", 2), "character", rep("NULL", 37)))
```

but I get this error when trying to load it: **`R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes`|**

Anyway to skip those values ?

Comment: You could try [vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) and exclude that column, although something doesn't seem right - do you really have a 2.1Gb string in your dataset? Or maybe fread isn't reading in the data properly...

Comment: I can't exclude the column since it's the most important one. Hard to tell if it's reading properly I don't know the exact line of the error. It does read properly the first millions lines, I've tested it though.

Comment: can you narrow down the row on which the problem occurs by bisection (i.e. use the `skip` and `nrows` arguments to read the first half, second half, second quarter, etc. ... you can even automate this by using `try()` (and `if (inherits(result, "try-error")) ...` to narrow down the location of the problem.

Comment: It sounds like your CSV may be malformed. The most likely cause is mismatching quotes. Perhaps you can ask the person who generated the file originally to fix the errors.

Comment: I tried what you said but it seemed random, my CSV is fine it works perfectly in sql

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strategy that may work or at least narrow down the possible sources of error. It assumes you have enough working memory to hold the data and that your separators are really commas. If you actually have tabs as separators then you will need to modify accordingly. The plan is to read using `readLines` which will basically ignore the quotes that are probably mismatched. Then figure out which line or lines are at fault using `count.fields`,  `table`, and `which`.

```
 input <- readLines("data.csv")   # ignores quotes
 counts.def <- count.fields(textConnection(input),
                            sep=",")  # defaults quotes are both ' and "
 table(counts.def) # might show a variety of line counts.

# Second try with just double-quotes
 counts.dbl <- count.fields(textConnection(input),
                            sep=",", quote="\"") # just dbl-quotes
 table(counts.dbl) # if all the same, then all you do is change the quotes argument
```

Depending on the results you may need to edit cerain lines which can be identified using `which(counts.def < 40)` assuming most of them are 40 as your input efforts suggest is the expected number of fields per line.

(If the tag for `[ram]` means you are limited and getting warnings or using virtual memory which slows things down horribly, then you should restart your OS, and only load R before trying again. R needs contiguous block of memory and Windoze isn't very good at memory management.)

Here's a small test case to work with:

```
input <- readLines(textConnection(
"v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6 
text, text, text, text, text, text 
text, text, O'Malley, text,text,text 
junk,junk, more junk, \"text\", tex\"t, nothing 
3,4,5,6,7,8")
```